# Bootstrap Grid and column offset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following html:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            .col-sm-5
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
           .col-sm-5 .col-sm-offset-2
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Which result into the following: [image]

According to the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) it should fit perfectly into the row. But clearly there is somethin wrong, which I can't figure out.

When I take 11-columns into account it fits (notice col-sm-4 on the last DIV instead of col-sm-5):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            .col-sm-5
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
           .col-sm-5 .col-sm-offset-2
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong in my first html?

Comment: Working fine for me .. please check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bxd12auh/1/

Comment: Use `-xs-` classes.

Comment: `-xs-` classes doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in full screen, may be replacing with `xs` will help you! I am on **`1366`** width resolution. Clicking on the full page in below snippet works fine for me.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      .col-sm-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5">
      .col-sm-5 .col-sm-offset-2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since this totally depends on the **screen size**, I strongly believe your screen size is not accommodating `sm`, so using `xs` will show it in the right way.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      .col-xs-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-5">
      .col-xs-5 .col-xs-offset-2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I noted that you are using `border`s. So make sure you give this:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, my screen size is 2560px wide so that would accomodate `sm` isn't it? ;-). Replacing with `xs` didn't do anything for me, let me update my question as the problem may be somewhere else in the HTML

Comment: Also I'm not using the `container-fluid`

Comment: @AndrewFlierman Ah! There you are. **1.** Try using the CDN, as it looks like your `bootstrap.css` is modified. **2.** If that doesn't work, try using `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 0):

We're using `bootstrap-sass` and there was an inconsistency with the order of imports of the bootstrap files. Once the order was correct the issue is gone.